# How to have a custom background colour on a material toolbar?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I have [an app](https://stephaneeybert.github.io/stephaneeybert/musicng/soundtracks) for which I made a custom theme with a background colour:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$custom-theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-lime);
$custom-theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-orange, A200, A100, A400);
$custom-theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

$custom-theme: mat-light-theme($custom-theme-primary, $custom-theme-accent, $custom-theme-warn);

$custom-background-color: map_get($mat-grey, 0);
$background: map-get($custom-theme, 'background');
$background: map_merge($background, ('background': $custom-background-color));
$custom-theme: map_merge($custom-theme, ('background': $background));

@include angular-material-theme($custom-theme);
```

Now, I'm trying to have the `mat-toolbar` containing the right hand button have the same whitish colour as the `mat-card` background colour.

But the toolbar background remains grey.

I wish I could do without the toolbar that contains this button, but it's the way I found to have it align right.

I'm sure there are some CSS ways to achieve this, but I prefer not to dive into CSS hacking. I consider Angular Material is there to protect me.

The template markup is:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="background">
      <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
      <button mat-fab color="accent" (click)="generateSoundtrack()">
        <mat-icon mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-toolbar>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

The CSS file companion to the template:

```
.fill-remaining-space {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.soundtrack-action {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.soundtrack {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

mat-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

UPDATE: I could solve my issue of the differing background colours with the following theme configuration:

```
// Applying a custom theme
$palette-primary: mat-palette($mat-lime);
$palette-accent: mat-palette($mat-orange);
$palette-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$standard-light-theme: mat-light-theme($palette-primary, $palette-accent, $palette-warn);
@include angular-material-theme($standard-light-theme);

// Changing some palette properties of a theme and applying it to a component
$background: map-get($standard-light-theme, background);
$bg-color: #FFFFFF;
$background: map_merge($background, (background: $bg-color, app-bar: $bg-color));
$custom-light-theme: map_merge($standard-light-theme, (background: $background));
@include mat-toolbar-theme($custom-light-theme);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, in the example that I am going to show you, use an alternative theme for the material button component, you can use an alternative theme for any material component ([altertive-material-component-theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#changing-styles-at-run-time)).

The other options you have:

- [Customizing Angular Material component styles](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles)
- [Theming your custom component with Angular Material's theming system](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components)

And this is the working example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-how-to-have-a-custom-background-colour-on-a-material-to)

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody has this problem with newer angular versions, Stephane's adapted solution for me was:

```scss
    $background: map-get(map-get($my-theme, color), background);
    $bg-color: #FFF;
    $background: map_merge($background, (background: $bg-color, app-bar: 
    $bg-color, status-bar: $bg-color));
    $color-of-theme: map_merge(map-get($my-theme, color), (background: $background));
    $my-theme: map_merge($my-theme, (color: $color-of-theme));
```

The styles are now saved in a "color" field inside the theme map AND also duplicated directly to the map (needed for legacy support apparently, but imho this is very confusing and bad design). For my case I had to set the styles of the "color" field values, which the above code does. Code is called after initialising a theme - eg. `my-$theme: mat.define-light-theme((color:(primary:$primary-palette,accent: ....)));`  -> [more info](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-theme).